# SQL - Collect Oldest and Latest Records, and Get Days Between

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Using: SQL Server 2008 R2**

Is it possible, without using a CTE, to get the oldest and latest records, and then get the days between (DATEDIFF) within a single SELECT statement?

To clarify, here is my current SELECT statement:

```sql
SELECT 
COUNT(*) as 'Sessions', 
MAX(f_sessiondate) AS 'Latest', 
MIN(f_sessiondate) as 'Oldest'
```

So, say I get the following result

```
Sessions          Latest                         Oldest  
2610              2014-10-28 00:00:00.000        2013-12-23 00:00:00.000
```

What I want is to get the "Average Sessions Per Day" by doing a DATEDIFF between the 'Latest' and 'Oldest' entries. So the 'days' would be 309, and "Average Sessions Per Day" would be 8.45 (rounded).

**EDIT**:

By some stroke of luck, I got it to work to some degree, though I'm  missing my decimals. Here's what I added:

```
CAST(COUNT(*) / DATEDIFF(day, MIN(f_sessiondate),MAX(f_sessiondate)) as DECIMAL(18,2)) as 'Average Sessions Fixed',
```

Based on the (updated) numbers above, I should receive a result of 8.44 (309 days). However, SQL is giving me the result of 8.00. How can I get the proper decimals?

Thanks in advance,

Beems

Comment: You should cast your count(*) as a decimal.

Comment: CAST(cast(COUNT(*) as decimal) / DATEDIFF.....)

Comment: That did it, thank you. Can you please post that as an official answer so I can mark it?

Comment: I think you should add 1 to the result of DATEDIFF() because the sessions in your example occurred on two different days. Equally if MIN(f_sessiondate) = MAX(f_sessiondate), you will get a division by zero error. Better, if you can, to save a full timestamp, take the difference in hours and divide by 24.

Comment: Sure, although it seems you mostly answered your own question.

Comment: @grahamj42 Thank you for the insight. I came across this exact problem today, struggling for an hour as I tried to pry through the data to determine what the issue was before I vaguely remembered someone mentioning this in my post here. Multiple upvotes to your comment is deserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default counts are integers and any mathematical operations will result in an integer. To produce a decimal, first cast the count(*) to a decimal before performing operations.

```
CAST(CAST(COUNT(*) as Decimal) / DATEDIFF(day, MIN(f_sessiondate),MAX(f_sessiondate)) as DECIMAL(18,2)) as 'Average Sessions Fixed',
```